# How could I implement a scrolling window inside another?

Tags: c, ncurses

I am embedding my command line application into a ncurses-TUI. 
My application (client/server) should be able to print a lot lines if needed, but it must stays into the windows I defined :

```
    /* Removed code */
    ITEM **my_items;
    int c;
    MENU *my_menu;
    WINDOW *my_menu_win;
    int n_choices, i;

    // Initialize curses
    initscr();                              // initializes the screen
    start_color();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
    /* Removed code */
    /* Create items */
    n_choices = ARRAY_SIZE(choices);
    my_items = (ITEM **)calloc(n_choices, sizeof(ITEM *));
    for(i = 0; i < n_choices; ++i)
    {
        my_items[i] = new_item(choices[i], choices[i]);
    }

    /* Removed code */
    /* Create menu */
    my_menu = new_menu((ITEM **)my_items);

    /* Set menu option not to show the description */
    menu_opts_off(my_menu, O_SHOWDESC);

    /* Create the window to be associated with the menu */
    my_menu_win = newwin(WIN_HEIGHT, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_YPOS, WIN_XPOS);
    keypad(my_menu_win, TRUE);

    /* Set main window and sub window */
    set_menu_win(my_menu, my_menu_win);
    set_menu_sub(my_menu, derwin(my_menu_win,  WIN_HEIGHT/2, WIN_WIDTH/2, WIN_HEIGHT/2-3, WIN_WIDTH/2-10));

    /* Set menu mark to the string " * " */
    set_menu_mark(my_menu, ">");

    /* Print a border around the main window and print a title */
    box(my_menu_win, 0, 0);
    /* Removed code */
    /* Post the menu */
    post_menu(my_menu);
    wrefresh(my_menu_win);

    endwin();       //resets the screen
}
```

[image]

**1**  How can I add a windows inside this windows with a scrolling content where all the output that usually goes to the terminal would be print

**2**  ...or is it possible to link that windows with the terminal output ?

Comment: The question is unclear: the only interesting window shown is for the menu. A quick test shows that the menu library scrolls the content of the menu to display menu items when there are too many to display at one time.  You can create another window which (for instance) temporarily obscures the menu window; however it would be easier to use if you laid the windows out to not overlap.